# how to get values from addition conf files included in application.conf in scala

Tags: scala, configuration, akka

Hi I am trying to create additional conf files and include them in application.conf but i am unable to fetch my values I am definitely making mistakes here is my files

application.conf

```
include "DirectUserWriteMongoActor"

akka {
   loggers = ["akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger"]
   loglevel = "DEBUG"

}
```

DirectUserWriteMongoActor.conf

```
akka {
    actor{
    my-dispatcher {

    throughput = 10
                  }   
     }
}
```

i want to get the throughput value in my code but i am getting badpath exception Here is my code

```
 val config = ConfigFactory.load("application/DirectUserWriteMongoActor")
      println("throughput is "+config.getString("akka.actor.my-dispatcher.throughput"))
```

Comment: What error are you getting

Comment: Also, you should not have to explicitly load `DirectUserWriteMongoActor`.  You are including it in `application.conf`, so if you load `application.conf` via `ConfigFactory.load()` the additional config from that include should be available in your config tree.

Comment: thanks its working now after relpaceing this ConfigFactory.load("application/DirectUserWriteMongoActor") with ConfigFactory.load()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you should need to do here is to call `ConfigFactory.load()`.  When you do that, as long as it can find `application.conf` on the classpath, it will load it and then properly include the other conf file `DirectUserWriteMongoActor` due to your use of the `include` directive.